# Receiving different array format for files from web and android device

Tags: php, android, arrays, file-upload

I am writing code to upload files.Files may come from web(html form) or android application

From web ,the files are received in followig  array format

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => child.png [1] => child_513c5ea73bee8.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpFD18.tmp [1] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpFD19.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 13210 [1] => 7857 ) )
```

But from android application the files are received in following array format

```
  Array( [file1] => Array( [name] => child.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpFD18.tmp [error] => 7857 ) [file2] => Array( [name] => child_513c5ea73bee8.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpFD19.tmp [error] => 7857))
```

Why these files are received in different array formats?

Is there any way to receive files in common array format?

Comment: How is the upload form looks like ?
1st seems to be ok, but with the 2nd case, you can not "predict" how many inputs will you have.
(but anyhow it is possible to make a workaround for this based on the data you posted)

Comment: Can you post the code for uploaders o.O

Comment: As a workaround you can try this----> instead of using inbuilt code for file uploading, use a popup window having a webview that loads the uploader page in it.